# /tmp/laravel-excel does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel

so i am using [laravel excel](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel/tree/3.1) for importing .csv files and because the .csv files contain a lot of data then i running the import using laravel queue with redis driver

everything working just fine at local server at my mac using valet

but the problem occur when i tried the same code at production server at our vps that managed using runcloud

and it is only happen if i am using queue driver beside snyc. so if i change it to use database driver or redis driver then the error come.

after doing multiple debuging i find out that the error is because it can't create \tmp\ files for this plugins for doing import

to help find the key issue here is my configuration

```
"php": ">=7.1.3",
"maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
"laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
"predis/predis": "^1.1",
```

and here is stacktrace from laravel.log

```
[2022-01-06 14:57:14] local.ERROR: File "/tmp/laravel-excel-kzUS1G2AIXnig0Z1VKs5AegK3ar98WRS.csv" does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): File \"/tmp/laravel-excel-kzUS1G2AIXnig0Z1VKs5AegK3ar98WRS.csv\" does not exist. at /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Shared/File.php:137)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/BaseReader.php(152): PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\Shared\\File::assertFile()
#1 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Csv.php(540): PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\Reader\\BaseReader->openFile()
#2 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Csv.php(349): PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\Reader\\Csv->canRead()
#3 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Csv.php(330): PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\Reader\\Csv->loadIntoExisting()
#4 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Jobs/ReadChunk.php(118): PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\Reader\\Csv->load()
#5 [internal function]: Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Jobs\\ReadChunk->handle()
#6 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array()
#7 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#8 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#9 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#10 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
#11 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->Illuminate\\Bus\\{closure}()
#12 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#13 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#14 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(49): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->dispatchNow()
#15 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(83): Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler->call()
#16 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(326): Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\Job->fire()
#17 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(276): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->process()
#18 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(118): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->runJob()
#19 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->daemon()
#20 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(85): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker()
#21 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
#22 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array()
#23 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#24 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#25 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#26 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(179): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
#27 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute()
#28 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(166): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run()
#29 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run()
#30 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand()
#31 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun()
#32 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(89): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run()
#33 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run()
#34 /home/runcloud/webapps/puskopcuina/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#35 {main}"}
```

**update**

here is my config/excel.php

```
<?php

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;

return [
    'exports'            => [

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Chunk size
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | When using FromQuery, the query is automatically chunked.
        | Here you can specify how big the chunk should be.
        |
        */
        'chunk_size' => 1000,

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Temporary path
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | When exporting files, we use a temporary file, before storing
        | or downloading. Here you can customize that path.
        |
        */
        'temp_path'  => sys_get_temp_dir(),

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | CSV Settings
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Configure e.g. delimiter, enclosure and line ending for CSV exports.
        |
        */
        'csv'        => [
            'delimiter'              => ',',
            'enclosure'              => '"',
            'line_ending'            => PHP_EOL,
            'use_bom'                => false,
            'include_separator_line' => false,
            'excel_compatibility'    => false,
        ],
    ],

    'imports' => [

        'heading_row' => [

            /*
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Heading Row Formatter
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |
            | Configure the heading row formatter.
            | Available options: none|slug|custom
            |
            */
            'formatter' => 'slug',
        ],

        'csv' => [
            'delimiter'              => '|',
            'enclosure'              => '"',
            'line_ending'            => PHP_EOL,
            'use_bom'                => false,
            'include_separator_line' => false,
            'excel_compatibility'    => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Extension detector
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Configure here which writer type should be used when
    | the package needs to guess the correct type
    | based on the extension alone.
    |
    */
    'extension_detector' => [
        'xlsx'     => Excel::XLSX,
        'xlsm'     => Excel::XLSX,
        'xltx'     => Excel::XLSX,
        'xltm'     => Excel::XLSX,
        'xls'      => Excel::XLS,
        'xlt'      => Excel::XLS,
        'ods'      => Excel::ODS,
        'ots'      => Excel::ODS,
        'slk'      => Excel::SLK,
        'xml'      => Excel::XML,
        'gnumeric' => Excel::GNUMERIC,
        'htm'      => Excel::HTML,
        'html'     => Excel::HTML,
        'csv'      => Excel::CSV,
        'tsv'      => Excel::TSV,

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | PDF Extension
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Configure here which Pdf driver should be used by default.
        | Available options: Excel::MPDF | Excel::TCPDF | Excel::DOMPDF
        |
        */
        'pdf'      => Excel::DOMPDF,
    ],
];
```

Comment: Is the queue worker run on the same instance or different instance? Could you please also add the `config/excel.php` to the question?

Comment: @DharmaSaputra okay i already add config excel to my question

Comment: Honestly, I never use Runcloud. But curious how the queue worker being set up in your server infrastructure. Based on the error, it's not It can't create the file in the `/tmp` folder. It's more like the worker couldn't get the file to process it. This kind of issue commonly happens for multiple server setup, if the queue worker has different instance with the web server.  Because the instance is different, the worker counldn't find it in his own `/tmp` folder.

Answer (score 2):

```html
It working!

Please edit file config/excel.php
PHP higher version (>=7.1.3)

// 'local_path'  => sys_get_temp_dir(),
'local_path'  => storage_path('framework/cache/laravel-excel'),

PHP lower version (<=7.1.3)

// 'temp_path'  => sys_get_temp_dir(),
    'temp_path'  => storage_path('framework/cache/laravel-excel'),

Edit 'temp_path' or 'local_path' to folder storage in your project.

// And run cmd in your project directory:
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear

Good luck! @@
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If anyone fix problem with is in live/C_Panel/Hosting  use

**"'temp_path'  => storage_path('framework/cache/laravel-excel'),"**

and must add the class on the top

***use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel as ExcelExcel;***

And in the controller must ensure this:

**return Excel::download(new BookingExport($data),'booking-report.xlsx',ExcelExcel::XLSX);**

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was that `Laravel Excel` import was handled via base [Queued Job](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#dispatching-jobs)

```
<?php
MyJob::dispatch(); //WRONG
```

Solution is to use **Laravel Excel based** [Queued reading](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/queued.html). Also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77988787/724816)